# Django create model object and list without saving it

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.4

I have for example something like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)

class OrderLines(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quanity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

Now on my page want to do something like that (maybe my approach in design is wrong):

1. I receive POST data with product_id and quanity and store it as simple dictionary in session as 'ORDER_LINES' variable
2. When user clicks "Make order" I want to create `Order` object simply:

(I'm using generic views)

```
class ShowOrderPreview(TemplateView):
    template_name = "shop/order_preview.html"
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowOrderPreview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        order = Order(user = self.request.user)
        for product, quanity in self.request.session.get('ORDER_LINES', {}):
            order.orderlines_set.add( product=get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id), quanity=quanity)
        context['tmp_order'] = order
        return context
```

I dont want to that order be stored in database and only after user confirmation create it again and save.

I'm receiving: `"Column 'order_id' cannot be null"` on line `order.orderlines_set.add(...`

I know that the fastest solution will be create something like `DummyOrder` and `DummyOrderLines` with structure like the sam like my main `Order` and `OrderLines` object

I'm using `Django 1.4.1`.

Comment: YOu might be overcomplicating it a little bit. But for what you are looking for, in the view, on the `ModelForm`, you can do `form.save(commit=False)` that gives you the object without saving into the database

Comment: why don't you use Many to Many relation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @karthikr but it will be committed after leaving method but I will use manual transactions. To enable it in generic views simply decorate like `@login_required` in urls.py